# Uncaught TypeError: Iterator value undefined is not an entry object" Adding filter to map

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I am trying to iterate through an array of objects to create a new Object that fits my plan ahead better. Everything works fine until I put a if sentence in the map and I have no clue why?

```js
const TestArray = [{
    value: 0.2,
    Time: '1980',
    Region: 'Oklahoma',
    RegionNumber: '1620',
    validTo: 2017
  },
  {
    value: 0.3,
    Time: '1983',
    Region: 'Oklahoma',
    RegionNumber: '1620',
    validTo: 2017
  },
  {
    value: 0.2,
    Time: '1986',
    Region: 'Oklahoma',
    RegionNumber: '1620',
    validTo: 2017
  },
  {
    value: 0.2,
    Time: '1988',
    Region: 'Oklahoma',
    RegionNumber: '1620',
    validTo: 2017
  },
  {
    value: 0.2,
    Time: '2018',
    Region: 'Oklahoma',
    RegionNumber: '1620',
    validTo: 2017
  }
]
console.log("This works fine:")
console.log(Object.fromEntries(TestArray.map((item) => [item["Time"], item["value"]])))
console.log("but when adding filter it crashes:")
console.log(Object.fromEntries(TestArray.map((item) => {
  if (!(parseInt(item["validTo"]) > item["Time"])) {
    [item["Time"], item["value"]]
  }
})))
```

Comment: You are not returning from your `.map()` callback. You should use `.filter()` followed by `.map()` if you want to remove elements and then map them.

Comment: @NickParsons Ah that worked thanks, Could you maybe link me to a site explaining why the if sentence makes the error happen as I don't really understand why still? But what you suggested fixed my problem.

Comment: The [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method won't ever remove elements, it will always return an array of the same length. So you must map each element from `TestArray` to another element by returning that from your callback. If you don't return anything, then you get `undefined` (so you end up with `[undefined, undefined, ...]` as the mapped array) that you then pass to `Object.fromEntries()`. This method doesn't expect to see `undefined`, it instead expects to see a `[key, value]` pair array, so your code crashes

Answer (score 14):

If anyone is ending up on this Question while working with the JavaScript `Map` object like me:

```
const map = new Map(["a", 1], ["b", 2]);    // Iterator value is not an entry object
const map = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]);  // Correct, just forgot the []
```

Comment: I had the same problem. I was cloning a map `var newMap = new Map(myMap)`. You get  this error when `myMap` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the corrected code below

```
Object.fromEntries(TestArray.map((item) => {
  if (!(parseInt(item["validTo"]) > item["Time"])) {
    return [item["Time"], item["value"]]
  }
}).filter(item => item))
```

I have seen that you have already understood why your code did not work with the comments above.